# D3 Animating a Graph onLoad of page

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, visualization

I'm trying to animate my d3 graphs on load of the page from left to right using maybe the elastic tween but I am somewhat new to d3 and trying to learn so I am sure this is very simple but I can't seem to find a good example to help me with this. I have attached the html and the json if needed to help.

Also curious if somebody knows how to apply a border radius effect to the right side of each bar to curve the edges?

```
  <html>


   <head>
   <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

   <style>
    .canvas {background: #03ff01;
      height: 30em;
      width:70em;
      float: left;
      position: absolute;
      z-index:-1;
     }

     svg {padding-top:3em;
      stroke:black;
      stroke-width:1;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;}

  </style>
  </head>

  <body>
  <div class = "canvas">
  <script>

  d3.json("mydata2.json", function(data){

    var fill = d3.scale.category10();

    var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", 1000)
      .attr("height", 1000)

      canvas.selectAll("rect")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("width", function (d) { return d.amount * 10; })
        .attr("height", 46)
        .attr("y", function (d, i) {return i * 50;})
        .style("fill", function(d, i) { return fill(i); })


        canvas.selectAll("text")
          .data(data)
          .enter()
              .append("text")
              .style("font-family", "Impact")
              .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
              .attr("fill", "White")
              .attr("x", function (d, i) {return i + 10; })
              .attr("y", function (d, i) {return i * 50 + 28; })
              .text (function (d) {return d.name +": $" +d.amount;})


     })
   </script>
   </div>
   </body>
   </html>


   //JSON FILE CODE
   mydata2.json
   [
     {"name": "Maria", "amount": 30},
     {"name": "Fred", "amount": 50},
     {"name": "Francis", "amount": 12},
     {"name": "Gerry", "amount": 68},
     {"name": "Tony", "amount": 90}
   ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very simple example you can play around with:

```
canvas.selectAll("rect")
    .attr("width", 0)
    .transition()
    .delay(function(d, i){ return i*50; })
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("width", function (d) { return d.amount * 10; })
```

It works by first setting the width of all the `<rect>`s to `0`, and then creating an animation lasting 1 second (1000 milliseconds) to expand each of them to their full width. There's also a slight delay, so that the transition for the `<rect>`s don't all happen at the same time.

Note that -- just like in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23120813/transition-height-onload-of-d3js-rect-svg) -- you *must* set the width of each `<rect>` to `0` before performing the transition, so D3 has a starting value for the animation.

Comment: thank you that worked perfectly, trying to now apply the same delay of the text which appears inside each bar to fade in upon the loading of each bar. any ideas or suggestions? thanks again :)